# Android Image Edit and Use it in app

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am trying to upgrade [AimAssistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextgenintl.aimassistant) so that the user can customise the crosshair.
I am planning to allow the user to change colour, opacity, and size.
I have researched, but there aren't any specific directions on how to achieve this.
How can I change the colour, opacity, and size of an image, and save it in the drawable folder?

Comment: Maybe you could save the image online.The user could set a local image  and save it to the server.The app load the image from the server everytime.

Comment: But then the user would need internet connection all the time!

Comment: You could cache the image resource when you have the internet,then use the cache when you lose the connection.